# Youtube player api how to bind getCurrentTime() to a form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, video, youtube

I am trying to have a youtube video play through the javascript player api and allow the user to hit pause during playback and get the current time in seconds. I would like to know how to show the seconds counting in a form input. I can print out the current time with a javascript alert but do not know how to apply it to the form input.

Here is my current form attempt.

```
    <input type="text" id="link" name="link" value="player.getCurrentTime();" onClick="alert(player.getCurrentTime());" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all you need to add an event listener to your player so that you can detect the state changes

```
document.getElementById('MY-PLAYER-ID').addEventListener('onStateChange', 'player_state_changed');
```

After this, fire a function whenever the state changes to paused

```
function player_state_changed(state) {
    if(state==2)
    {
        //$('#input_id').val(player.getCurrentTime());
    }
}
```